# get.JSON not working on device

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I'm new to jQuery and working right now on requesting data from a json-File on a server at App initialisation. I'm using the Intel XDK with jQuery.
The code for the complete script is at this moment:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        // Helper Functions

     String.prototype.format = function() {
        var args = arguments;
        return this.replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function (m, n) {return args [n]; });
     };

    // Page init Handler    

    $(document).bind('pageinit', function (event) {
     var page = event.target.baseURI.split('/'); 
        page = page[page.length -1];

        if (!App.initialized) {
            App.initialized = true;
            App.init();    
        }

        switch(page){
        case 'index.html':
                break;
        case 'maps.html':
                break;
        case 'agenda.html':
                Agenda.init();
                break;
        case 'travel.html':
                break; 
        }
    });

     var App = {  
      initialized: false,
        agenda: null,
        init: function (){
            this.cacheAgenda();
        },
        cacheAgenda: function() {
            var me = this;
            var url = "http://myurl/batteries1-4.json";
            $.getJSON(url, function(data1){
                //Sort data by Talk
               data1.sort(function(a,b){
                   return (a.Title < b.Title) ? -1 : (a.Title > b.Title) ? 1 : 0 
                })

                me.agenda=data1;
                console.log(data1);
            });
        }
    };


    //Agenda Objects

    var Agenda = {
    init: function() {
        this.populateList();
    },
    populateList: function(){
            var talk_list=$('#li_Talk > ul');
            talk_list.empty();
            var TalkTemplate=$("#tplTalkItem").html();
            for (var i=0; i<App.agenda.length; i++){
                var item = App.agenda[i];
                talk_list.append(
                TalkTemplate.format(
                    item.Time_tag,
                    item.Time,
                    item.Title,
                    item.Author
                    )
                )
            };
            talk_list.listview("refresh");
    }    

    }          
</script>
```

When I'm running the code on the emulator device, it works perfectly fine. App.agenda shows an Array which I can work with.
Wehen I'm running the compiled App on Android or iOS App.agenda don't contain any Data and the debugger does't show an error.
Any idea how I can get the code working?

PS: I've wrote the code corresponding to [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/articles/fast-track-to-intel-xdk-new-data) tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried using something other than `console.log(data1)` to display the result? Does it help if you display the agenda json object via `$(body).append(data1);`?

Comment: No I doesn't tried something other since there is no log at all on the device. Therefore I think the function isn't executed at all.

Comment: A lot of possibility here, maybe it's because of the URL to get the data, or maybe the json file is not copied into the device package.. will need you to post some error log to determine the cause.

Comment: Adding on to what @ipohfly suggested, you could do some error handling on the JSONP call by way of `$.getJSON("http://myurl/batteries1-4.json", function() {
  $(body).append("success");
})
.success(function() { $(body).append("second success"); })
.error(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        $(body).append("error " + textStatus);
        $(body).append("incoming Text " + jqXHR.responseText);
    })
.complete(function() { $(body).append("complete"); });`

Comment: Or simply `jQuery.getJSON(...).done(function(){ if ok }).error(function(){ if error });`

Comment: Thank you @chridam and ipohfly!
I've edited the code corresponding to your suggestion.
On the device the output is:
"error error"
"incoming text"
"complete"

-no errors are displayed in the console